# Angular Ladda button disabled and blank: ie. not working

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to use angular-ladda and only seeing a blank button when it should show the spinner icon:

[image: blank button]

All css and modules are loaded properly.

Here's the code used in the HTML:

```
<button ladda="news.working" class="ladda-button btn btn-primary" data-style="zoom-in" ng-click="news.setup()">
        Update Settings
</button>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, the simple fix is to add `data-spinner-size` as an attribute to the HTML:

```
<button ladda="news.working" class="ladda-button btn btn-primary" data-style="zoom-in" data-spinner-size="25" ng-click="news.setup()">
            Update Settings
</button>
```